# Paperclip config for Amazon S3 and local uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using rails 4.2 and paperclip 4.2.1. I have several rails model with paperclip attachments so I set default config for paperclip in `development.rb` like this:

`config.paperclip_defaults = config_for(:paperclip_settings)`

and set `paperclip_settings.yml` to:

`development:
  :storage: :s3
  :s3_credentials:
    :bucket: "xxx"
    :access_key_id: "yyy"
    :secret_access_key: "zzz"
  :url: ':s3_path_url'
  :path: '/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename`

and I've added one more attachment only for one model that must saves locally

`has_attached_file :faq, :storage => :filesystem` but it still tries to save this attachment to S3. So the question is how can I separate config for S3 and filesystem uploading and call them on paperclip `has_attached_file` or just fill all needed properties to this attachment.

Thanks!